# cmyk rgb gnuplot and prologues

Tags: gnuplot, rgb, postscript, cmyk

For a publication I am required to convert all my nice little GnuPlot (and PowerPoint) pictures from RGB to CMYK. In theory it does not seem so complicated but apparently no non-commercial programme is able to solve it.

I am using GnuPlot for my figures. Is there a simple command to convert my rgb files to cmyk? I have read a lot about "editing the prologue file". I found this file, however I have no clue what to do and where and on the interwebz nobody asked further after asking this question...
I am outputting with the following terminal:

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color solid linewidth 1 font "Helvetica" 11
```

I have spent a good couple of hours searching for a solution for this problem and apparently it is either very difficult to impossible or so easy that nobody clears up anything after solving it. I did not find any solutions so far, hope you guys can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ps2write device in Ghostscript. It won't 'convert' your files to CMYK, but it will create a new PostScript file which should be visually the same as the original, and can include colour conversion as part of the process.

Note that ps2write only supports  language level 2, so any level 3 constructs will be rendered to images, which may well be undesirable.